# Issue with Pythontex using a LaTeX editor (MacOS - Anaconda)

Tags: xetex, pythontex, macos, pygments

I just achieved a clean install of MacOS Mojave. I have reinstalled Pythontex with the help of TeX Live Utility. Python 3 is installed with Anaconda.
The package works fine when the typesetting is done with the following commands on a shell :

```
xelatex -8bit -synctex=1 filename
pythontex filename
xelatex -8bit -synctex=1 filename
```

The output is correct :

[image]

But I am not able to typeset with a classical bash script as above (for exemple with TexMaker or TeXPad) :

```
xelatex -shell-escape -8bit %.tex|pythontex %.tex|xelatex -shell-escape  -8bit %.tex|
```

Output
[image]
MVE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{pythontex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

ABCDE
1+2=

\begin{pyconsole}
1+1
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

In the log file I see `Package PythonTeX Warning: Missing autoprint content on input line 9.`

Comment: Your script does not call pythontex. Only XeLaTeX (and that thrice)…

Comment: I corrected my script.

Comment: Even now I would say that your script is not a typical bash script. In bash I would say `xelatex … && pythontex … && xelatex …`. I do not think that piping is the way to go.

Comment: Why note just use what works? Instead of `filename` use `$1` and save it (e.g., `mypythontex.sh`), make it executable and then run it as `mypythontex.sh filename`. You may have to put it in the same directory as `filename` and run it as `./mypythontex.sh filename`.

Comment: Thank you Herb Schulz for your suggestion. The file `mypythontex.sh` is perfect until I find a solution for typesetting directly with Texmaker or TexPad.

Comment: @jowe_19 if you are satisfied with your solution, please post the answer and marked it as solved/accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it specifying an explicit path : `python /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin/pythontex filename` instead of `pythontex filename`